# Removing duplicates based on multiple conditions, including max. date

Tags: r, duplicates, max

If I data frame that looks like this:

```
ID  Code  Desc.  Expiry Date
1   2C    Long   2018-02-01
1   2C    Long   2020-02-01
2   NA    Tall   2019-04-30
2   NA    Tall   2016-04-28
```

I want to remove duplicates when ID and Code are the same. I want to removed duplicates based on whichever one has the max. expiry date. The output I want would then be:

```
ID  Code  Desc.  Expiry Date
1   2C    Long   2020-02-01
2   NA    Tall   2019-04-30
```

I've tried

```
data <- data[!duplicated(data[c("ID", "CODE", MAX("Expiry Date"))]),]
```

But this results in

```
could not find function "MAX"
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do a group by 'ID', 'Code' and `slice` the row with the `max` 'Expiry Date'.  In `R`, `max` gets the `max`imum value, `which.max` the index of the max value

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
    group_by(ID, Code) %>%
    slice(which.max(`Expiry Date`))
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   ID, Code [2]
#     ID Code  Desc. `Expiry Date`
#  <int> <chr> <chr> <date>       
#1     1 2C    Long  2020-02-01   
#2     2 <NA>  Tall  2019-04-30
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, .SD[which.max(`Expiry Date`)], .(ID, Code)]
```

NOTE: There is no function named `MAX` in `base R`.  It is `max`.  Also, we assume the `Expiry Date` as `Date` class.  If not, it should be first converted to `Date` class with `as.Date`

---

In `base R`, we  can do an `order` based on the 'Expiry Date' and then use `duplicated`

```
data1 <- data[do.call(order, data[c('ID', 'Code', 'Expiry Date')]),]
data1[!duplicated(data1[c('ID', 'Code')], fromLast = TRUE),]
#  ID Code Desc. Expiry Date
#2  1   2C  Long  2020-02-01
#3  2 <NA>  Tall  2019-04-30
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), Code = c("2C", "2C", NA, 
NA), Desc. = c("Long", "Long", "Tall", "Tall"), 
`Expiry Date` = structure(c(17563, 
18293, 18016, 16919), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -4L
), class = "data.frame")
```